# List view threshold - Why is querying with key filters still possible without having an indexed field

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, managed-metadata, caml, list-view-threshold

I read a lot about the list view threshold topic, so I know, that it should not be increased, if you have large list. In short, as far as I read, it is recommended to create an index on a column and filter the view to this index.
We have currently the issue, that we are using multiple `managed metadata` fields and values to narrow down the list, but it is not possible to create an index on a `managed metadata` field, where multiple entries are allowed.
So our `CAML` query fails, if the list has more entries than specified in the list view threshold value (and because we are not querying a field with an index).

See these links for more info:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1076854/Overcoming-the-List-View-Threshold-in-SharePoint-C

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/a4c28a29-a127-43da-8f33-23e77fbc7188/list-view-threshold-and-managed-metadata-fields-with-multiple-values?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

But my question is now, why is it still possible to use the `key filters` in the library itself?
So there must be a way to query the list with `managed metadata` fields even when the threshold is exceeded and there is no index created.

[image]

Does anybody know, how the `key filters` work in the library?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that **Metadata Navigation and Filtering** and **Managed Metadata columns** are different objects in this topic.

Using Metadata Navigation and Filtering is actually a way to bypass the list/library threshold since it is more about filtering. “*Automatically manage column indices on this list*” option is selected by default via metadata navigation settings. The supported fields will be created as indexed column in the list.

Also quoting this [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-up-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-c222a75d-8b18-44e2-9ed8-7ee4e0d23cfc#ID0EAAEAAA=SharePoint_Server):

> The metadata navigation and filtering feature automatically selects
> the best index to work every time that a view is loaded. When users
> load new views, clear filters, or apply a sort, query optimization
> determines the best way in which to query the database to avoid list
> view throttling.

See the reference here: [Use filtering to modify a SharePoint view.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the links. But the question is still the same. It says in the link "If a user loads a view that exceeds the threshold, then metadata navigation and filtering creates a modified version of the original user query called a fallback query. The fallback query runs against a portion of the list instead of the complete list.". So it should be possible to run a `CAML` query against a portion of the list manually, too, shouldn't it? Actually I always get the error "the attempteed... it exceeds the list view threshold...".

Comment: @dns_nx That’s because you are already in a list view threshold situation. You should try reducing the numbers of items or number of managed metadata (Lookup) columns in your list before you try anything else. I’m not familiar with calling CAML query manually so I cannot say it is the same process.